# Device list doesn't shows in Android Studio using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-test

I tried to develop app using Flutter(using Android studio IDE).Add flutter plugin & flutter SDK in studio and  Everything is configured but emulator / real time device are not listed. Its shows error like "Unable to list devices: Unable to discover Android devices. Please run "flutter doctor" to diagnose potential issues"
[image: android studio with flutter]

Ref link : https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#android-setup

https://flutter.io/get-started/test-drive/#androidsstudio

Comment: Can you please try if executing `adb kill-server` on the command line helps? Also check if `adb devices` lists the available devices.

Comment: Do you have any emulators running? Or a physical device connected to your machine? If yes, then do `flutter devices` from the terminal and post the output

Comment: Emulater and device also running but device list not show there

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer after execute adb devices

C:\Users\Vadivel>adb devices

List of devices attached

emulator-5556   device
ZY223J8XGG      device

Comment: I fixed this problem, thanks all

Comment: @Vadivel how did you fix it ?

Comment: @Idee - Choose emulator x86 Images when Create a emulator

Comment: What of my real device ? @Vadivel

Comment: Once you added flutter plugin just restart you studio

Answer (score 65):

configure flutter in terminal to detect Android SDK and Android Studio:

```
$ flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk
$ flutter config --android-studio-dir /path/to/android/studio
```

then restart Android Studio/Intellij. 
source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2113#issuecomment-383412308

Comment: entered this command and restarted studio and start worked fine

Comment: This answer helped me, too, and it seems likely that it's the most common issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you configure flutter and android sdk both perfectly and you do not show the avd device list in android studio.

It's very simple way to show android emulator device list.

First create a new  Android Emulator if already create you run the AVD manager then you can show the instead of emulator name

Before: 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/6np0m.png

After:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiCYe.png

Answer (score 0):

May be there is no AVD's to list down. And if emulator runnig, intelliJ will grab it.

In Android Studio, you can create a AVD using AVD Manager or using Terminal. Here is how you can do that using Terminal,

First, go to the android sdk installed directory -> tools

and copy the path and in the terminal type `cd` and paste the path and press enter. Now yo are in the tools directory.

Next, using terminal type:

`emulator -list-avds` - to list created AVD's(You should be in tools directory to run this command).

If there is a device type `emulator -avd <name>`. else you can create a one:

type `cd bin` then,

Use:

`avdmanager create avd -n name -k "sdk_id" [-c {path|size}] [-f] [-p path]`

As a example:

```
avdmanager create avd -n Nexus -d 23 -k system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86
```

Then again go back to tools directory by typing `cd ..` and type `emulator -list-avds`. This command will list your created AVD.

To run a AVD type:

```
emulator -avd <name>
```

About [AVD](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after moving avd's to another disk.

I managed to solve by making `ANDROID_HOME` system variable to point to the android sdk path.

Answer (score 0):

**For mac users,**

It was working fine yesterday. In my case I had this in **.bash_profile**

```
ANDROID_HOME = Library/Android/sdk
```

I changed it to,

```
ANDROID_HOME = /Users/rana.singh/Library/Android/sdk
```

**.bash_profile** has

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/rana.singh/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

It worked.