# Flutter with Android Studio does not show Device List

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Installing Flutter with Android Studio does not show me the device list that I am expecting. When inspecting the same using the flutter devices it shows me results but not in the Android studio device list. Can anyone please tell me the solution. Adding some screenshot regarding the same.

[image]

Also here is the screenshot of the flutter doctor

[image]

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you try to restart your computer? (if you didn't do already) If you want to avoid that, you can also try `adb --kill-server` and killing all `dart` processes `killall -9 dart`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hey thanks , that worked. Restarted system twice but didn't work. But used the adb commands and killall command and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Weird. Restart should had have the same effect. Glad to hear you could solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restarting the computer should fix that.

If you want to avoid restarting, you can also use

```
adb --kill-server 
killall -9 dart
```

to killing all dart processes (they will be re-started on demand anyway)

Comment: I sometimes forgot that turning it off and turning it back on again is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Configure flutter in terminal to detect Android SDK and Android Studio:

```
$ flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk
$ flutter config --android-studio-dir /path/to/android/studio
```

Then restart Android Studio/Intellij. 
source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2113#issuecomment-383412308

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019226/3879756